# Lost private key for distribution, push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification

By doing a fresh install of OSX I lost my distribution certificates. (Stupid me) 
One of them is a vert for an app with pushnotifications in it. If I regenerate that cert, will I need a new certificate to send push notifications from my server? Will this be a problem with older versions?

Comment: Usually you just reject the existing cert and create a new one. This won't affect push notifications as you will just start using the new certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You just seemed to have lost the certs on your mac. But the generated distribution cert is still in your ios dev center/ itunes. All you need to do is download the distribution cert and
push cert again and install the certs in your key-chain.